# Concise Way of Get Matching Element in List

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like

```
[{'name': 'red', 'test':4},... {'name': 'reded', 'test':44}]`
```

I have a name (for example: `reded`) and I want to find the dictionary in the list above that has `name` in the dictionary set to `reded`. What is a concise way of doing so?

My attempts look something similar to

```
x = [dict_elem for dict_elem in list_above if dict_elem['name']==reded]
```

Then I do

```
final_val = x[0]
```

if the name gets matched. This can also be done with a `for loop` but it just seems like there is a simple one-liner for this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you can substitute your first line into your second... `[dict_elem for dict_elem in list_above if dict_elem['name']==reded][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there. If you use a generator- rather than list-comprehension, you can then pass it to `next`, which takes the first item.

```
try:
    x = next(dict_elem for dict_elem in list_above if dict_elem['name'] == reded)
except StopIteration:
    print "No match found"
```

Or

```
x = next((dict_elem for dict_elem in list_above if dict_elem['name'] == reded), None)
if not x:
    print "No match found"
```

Comment: The fastest fingers in the west.